# PySpark Kusto Connector on Azure Databricks

Tags: azure, pyspark, spark-streaming, azure-data-explorer, kusto-java-sdk

I am using Azure databricks with LTS 7.3 and spark 3.0 (PySpark) with com.microsoft.azure.kusto:kusto-spark_3.0_2.12:2.9.1 connector for quite sometime now but recently my jobs are failing with below errors (randomly, sometimes they run and othertimes they just simply fail)

```
df = pyKusto.read                                                        \
           .format("com.microsoft.kusto.spark.datasource")               \
           .option("kustoCluster", kustoOptions["kustoCluster"])          \
           .option("kustoDatabase", kustoOptions["kustoDatabase"])         \
           .option("kustoQuery", Query)                                    \
           .option("kustoAadAppId", kustoOptions["kustoAadAppId"])           \
           .option("kustoAadAppSecret", kustoOptions["kustoAadAppSecret"])    \
           .option("kustoAadAuthorityID", kustoOptions["kustoAadAuthorityID"]) \
           .load()
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: com.microsoft.kusto.spark.datasource. Please find packages at http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html
```

I have already installed the library on the cluster and it has been running for sometime without issues but not sure what's happening to it recently. Please suggest any workaround if anyone have seen this issue?

Thanks

Comment: 2 general comments: **(1)** There is reason to create a new spark context (`pyKusto`) when you're working with Databricks and there's already a pre-created one (`spark`). **(2)** wrap a multi-line expression with brackets, and you won't need all those new line symbols: `df = (pyKusto.read. ... .load())`.

Comment: I think @DavidדודוMarkovitz meant "There is _no_ reason to create a new spark context ..."

Answer (score 0):

In Databricks try to upgrade kusto-spark library from `kusto-spark_3.0_2.12:2.9.1` to `kusto-spark_3.0_2.12:3.0.0`:

Libraries -> Install New -> Maven -> copy the following coordinates:

```
com.microsoft.azure.kusto:kusto-spark_3.0_2.12:3.0.0
```

If it still not works, you can create new issue [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-kusto-spark/issues)

Refer - https://github.com/Azure/azure-kusto-spark#Linking

Comment: Even after upgrading the library, the jobs are still failing. I will have to raise a ticket

Answer (score 0):

Is a bit late but here is what works for me:

```py
df = spark.read                                                        \
           .format("com.microsoft.kusto.spark.datasource")               \
           .option("kustoCluster", kustoOptions["kustoCluster"])          \
           .option("kustoDatabase", kustoOptions["kustoDatabase"])         \
           .option("kustoQuery", Query)                                    \
           .option("kustoAadAppId", kustoOptions["kustoAadAppId"])           \
           .option("kustoAadAppSecret", kustoOptions["kustoAadAppSecret"])    \
           .option("kustoAadAuthorityID", kustoOptions["kustoAadAuthorityID"]) \
           .load()
```

So, **spark** instead of pykusto